# How to fix numpy dtype value error "invalid shape in fixed-type tuple"

Tags: python, bioinformatics, numpy-ndarray

Everyone!

I was running a python script in relation to a project I'm working on and came across an, "invalid shape in fixed-type tuple" error. Initially, I thought it was a problem having to do with syntax, or restructuring of the dataset, but haven't been able to fix it even after incorporating similar fixes that others have used for the same issue. If someone could help out with pointing me in the right direction that would be great!

Below I've attached two texts: The first one includes the error appearing in my terminal and the other shows the corresponding spot of the error in the python script. Line 632 is at the very end, thank you so much in advance and I look forward to your responses.

1.
line 632, in get_fragment_entry_dtype
("aa_w", np.float, (frag_size, 20))])
ValueError: invalid shape in fixed-type tuple.

2. ```
        def get_fragment_entry_dtype(num_fragment_atoms):
            frag_size=num_fragment_atoms/len(atom_types_arr)
            return np.dtype([("assignment", np.int), 
                                    ("size", np.int),
                                    ("avg_distance", np.float), 
                                    ("threshold_distance", np.float), 
                                    ("cordinates", np.float, (num_fragment_atoms, 3)), 
                                    ("bb", np.float, (frag_size, 3)), 
                                    ("ss", np.float, (frag_size, 3)),
                                    ("aa", np.float, (frag_size, 20)), 
                                    ("aa_w", np.float, (frag_size, 20))])
   ```

Comment: Welcome! Please [do not post code, errors and logs as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), but copy the relevant parts into the question instead, refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you! I've just done that, let me know if there's anything else I should change.